# Liquid Template: Append variable to data object

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have the following structure in my Jekyll app:

```
_data/
  test.json
items/
  test/
    index.html
```

I am using the following to grab just the name of the ending folder name of my item:

```
{% assign listing = {{ page.url | remove: 'items/' | replace:'/',' ' | truncatewords: 1 | remove:'...' | escape }} %}
```

What I'm then trying to do is access the data file which the matching folder name from the `_data` directory.

I've gotten it to:

```
{{ site.data.{{ listing }} }}
```

which allows me to see the data, but I can't actually go inside the JSON object to grab a specific item, like `{{ site.data.{{ listing }}.test }}` does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some brackets like this :

```
{% assign datas = site.data[{{listing}}] %}
```

You can now access `datas.test`.

Comment: Thanks David, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that example was hard to find in the Jekyll documentation!